# jQuery modal Dialog over iFrame

Tags: jquery, dialog, modal-dialog

I am using  jQuery UI dialog for modal popups. I have some iframes in my page as well. The iFrame (z-Index = 1500) sits on top of the parent page (z-index =1000). I open the modal dialog from the parent page. I am trying to set the z-index using $('modal').dialog('option','zIndex',3000); but this is not working.  I also tried stack:true (to stack it on top), and .dialog( 'moveToTop' ) as well, but they don't seem to work.

Here is the code:
Parent page:

using style sheet :  from "css/ui-darkness/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" 
using scripts:   jquery-1.3.2.min.js  && jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.min.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

  function TestModal() {
    var modal = "<div id='modal'>Hello popup world</div>";
    $(modal).dialog({
      modal: true,
      title: 'Modal Popup',
      zIndex: 12000,  // settin it here works, but I want to set it at runtime instead of setting it at design time
      close: function() {
        setTimeout(TestModal, 5000);
        $(this).remove();
      }
    });

    $('modal').dialog('option', 'zIndex', 11000); // these dont work
    $('modal').dialog('moveToTop'); // these dont work
    $('modal').dialog('option', 'stack', true); // these dont work
  }
    /** Run with defaults **/
  $(document).ready(function() {

    TestModal();

  });

  </script>
<div>
 Hello  World
 <br />

</div>

<iframe src="blocker.htm" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" name="myInlineFrame" 
style="z-index:10000;background-color:Gray;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px" ALLOWTRANSPARENCY="false">
</iframe>
```

iframe : blocker.htm

.wrap{width:100%;height:100%}

I am an iframe and I am evil

Comment: update: the 2 solutions provided did not work.  I am using http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/876332.aspx to find the max Z-index dynamically and then assign it at design time

something like   $(modal).dialog({ /* other properties */ ,  zIndex: $.maxZIndex()+ 1, })

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am using [this post](http://west-wind.com/weblog/posts/876332.aspx) to find the max Z-index dynamically and then assign it at design time something like:

```
$(modal).dialog({ /* other properties */ , zIndex: $.maxZIndex()+ 1, })
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
$('#modal').closest('div.ui-dialog').css('z-index', '3000')
```

jQuery UI Dialog renders a DIV with class *ui-dialog* and it becomes the parent of your original DIV, hence I used *closest()* to find it (not referencing it directly by class in case there are more dialogs on the page).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `$('modal').dialog('zIndex', 11000)` ?

Comment: I tried  $('modal').dialog('option', 'zIndex', 11000); but not   $('modal').dialog('zIndex', 11000); let me try

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an extension that will do what it is I think you are actually wanting...

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-framedialog